# laravel elixir - combining scripts multiple times

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I want to combine all my scripts into one minified javascript file, but I'm having trouble combining them.

```
mix.browserify([
  // ViewModels
  'viewmodels.js'
], 'resources/assets/compiled/js/viewmodels.js')

mix.coffee([
  // WebSocket Client
  'client.coffee'
], 'resources/assets/compiled/js/').scripts([
  // Vendor
  'vendor/jquery.js',
  'vendor/bootstrap.js',
  'vendor/vue.js',
  'vendor/sisyphus.js',
  'vendor/leaflet.js',
  'vendor/moment.min.js'
], 'resources/assets/compiled/js/vendor.js').scripts([
  // Site & Helpers
  'libs/laravel.js',
  'libs/helpers.js'
], 'resources/assets/compiled/js/site.js').scripts([
  // Combine Scripts
  'resources/assets/compiled/js/vendor.js',
  'resources/assets/compiled/js/client.js',
  'resources/assets/compiled/js/site.js',
  'resources/assets/compiled/js/viewmodels.js'
], 'public/js/all.js', './')
```

The files are created in `resources/assets/compiled/js`, so I've got:

- client.js
- site.js
- vendor.js
- viewmodels.js

The last task that's run is the `scripts` task combining the four files.
The elixir log states (I simplified the ouput):

- Browserify (ViewModels)
- CoffeeScript Compiled
- Merging Vendor
- Merging Site & Helpers
- Merging Combine Scripts

... and these are the error messages I get:

```
File not found: ./resources/assets/compiled/js/vendor.js
File not found: ./resources/assets/compiled/js/site.js
```

I did the exact same thing with `sass` and `styles` and it worked perfectly.

```
mix.sass([
  // Vendor
  'resources/assets/sass/fontawesome/font-awesome.scss',
  // Site
  'resources/assets/sass/site/site.scss'
], 'resources/assets/compiled/css/').styles([
  // Vendor
  'resources/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
  'resources/assets/css/hover-min.css',
  'resources/assets/css/leaflet.css',
  'resources/assets/compiled/css/font-awesome.css',
  // Site
  'resources/assets/compiled/css/site.css'
], 'public/css/all.css', './').version(
  'public/css/all.css'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you merging the scripts all at once instead of doing it 3 times ?

Try like this

```
mix.coffee([
  // WebSocket Client
  'client.coffee'
], 'resources/assets/compiled/js/')
  .scripts([
    // Vendor
    'resources/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js',
    'resources/assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/js/vendor/vue.js',
    'resources/assets/js/vendor/sisyphus.js',
    'resources/assets/js/vendor/leaflet.js',
    'resources/assets/js/vendor/moment.min.js',
    // Site & Helpers
    'resources/assets/js/libs/laravel.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/helpers.js',
    'resources/assets/compiled/js/client.js',
    'resources/assets/compiled/js/viewmodels.js'
  ], 'public/js/all.js', './');
```